# How to enable <aop:aspectj-autoproxy> with java-based annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am trying to set up Spring AOP without any XML. 
I'd like to enable `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>` in a class which is 
annotated with `@Configuration`.

This is the way it would be defined in an XML-file:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
<aop:include name="msgHandlingAspect" />
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
```

I tried to annotate my class with `@Configuration` and `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`
but nothing happened.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/EnableAspectJAutoProxy.html

Answer (score 48):

Did you create an aspect bean in the same `@Configuration` class?
Here's what [the docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/EnableAspectJAutoProxy.html) suggest:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableAspectJAutoProxy
 public class AppConfig {
     @Bean
     public FooService fooService() {
         return new FooService();
     }

     @Bean // the Aspect itself must also be a Bean
     public MyAspect myAspect() {
         return new MyAspect();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I created an aspect bean in the same @Configuration class as shown in your example. But still nothing happens. I now imported the <aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
<aop:include name="msgHandlingAspect" />
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
in an extra xml-file and added this via ImportResource to my Configuration class. Now the Aspect works. But the better way would be to have the configuration in the same Configuration class

Comment: Exactly what I looking for. Even the class name is the same with mine :D

Comment: I don't declare a @Bean for my Aspect , but the advice works, why?

Comment: @Jaskey picked up by component scan?

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd, yes, I use component scan in my xxx-servet.xml

Comment: @Jaskey hmmm, I can only explain that if your aspect is also annotated as `@Component`or similar. See [the relevant section of the manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-at-aspectj)

Comment: So, can I think that @component or @Bean-->return an instance is doing the same thing in Spring, which is trying to declare a bean for Spring container to hold?

Comment: yeah, pretty much. they are two different ways to achieve the same thing, make a class instantiated and managed by Spring

Comment: Thanks Sean. its very useful.

Comment: remember to add proxyTargetClass = true otherwise you can have unexpected errors if you used in controller
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)

Comment: @FarukT that's for when you use class-based proxies. I prefer to use interface based proxies.

Answer (score 3):

I used the accepted answer solution but I had unexpected problems and never understand untill to add this parameter to configuration.

**@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)**

If you use annotation into @Controller you'll need to configure in this way

remember if you have java 8 you need to use a version of AspectJ greater than 1.8.X

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public AccessLoggerAspect accessLoggerAspect() {
        return new AccessLoggerAspect();
    }

}
```